# Copy attachments from one gdb to another

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, copy, attachments

I have two GDB files with similar data at the attrib but slightly different geometry. However, one has an attachments of photos and one does not. I would like to copy the attachments from one to the other by using the similar attributes. I have already tried to use the "*add attachment*" tool but it doesn't copy the files. Does anybody knows a way that works?
I can work with both Arc pro or qgis.

Comment: If you are working with ESRI file GDB and and your attachement are created the ESRI way you should ask for an ArcPro solution (and remove the QGIS tag from your question)

Answer (score 1):

Copy one with attachments and wrong geometry to different gdb and start editing session. In the field calculator expression below change name of correct geometry layer in your table of content and matching IDs names. Run expression on "Shape" field:

```
    shapesDict ={}
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("CORRECT_GEOMETRY",("MATCH_ID","Shape@")) as cursor:
      for id,shp in cursor:shapesDict[id]=shp
    def fixShape(id):
     return shapesDict[id]
#----------

    fixShape( !ID!)
```

Don't forget to save your edits.